# how to find the deleted id after destroy in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

How to find the deleted Id in rails?
Example:

```
@order=Order.find(params[:id])
@order.destroy
//here I wan to get the deleted order id
```

Then how to find the Id already delete on next line?

Comment: If you're deleting the record based on `params` and you need the id still in the controller, why can't you just use the id in `params`?

Comment: First identify the problem, then do the question.

Comment: because after delete i also wan to get @order.order_products.ids

Comment: If you perform a destroy action from the view to the controller your "loaded" records won't "disappear" until you refresh the page. There's no way to get the order_products directly from an order object if it has been destroyed unless you store its id previously.

Comment: It sounds like you should not be deleting the order. Instead, why don't you add an boolean attribute to an order called cancelled, default: false. then when an order is cancelled, you change that attribute to true. nobody builds an app where orders are "destroyed".

Answer (score 0):

Change your second line of code to: `response=@order.destroy`.
then with `response.id` you can get the id of deleted object.

Then your code become:

```
@order=Order.find(params[:id])
response = @order.destroy
deleted_id = response.id
```

otherwise extract the id from delected obj istance:

```
@order=Order.find(params[:id])
@order.destroy
deleted_id = @order.id
```